# Numpy: subtract column from a matrix without repmats

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

Sorry for lack of research - I'm in a hurry.
When I do this

```
data = data-data[:,0]
```

I get a broadcast error. What do I do so that numpy understands me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend the slice to `2D` with [`None/np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and then subtract -

```
data -= data[:,0,None]
```

Alternatively, we can also reshape to get that 2D -

```
data -= data[:,0].reshape(-1,1)
```

Sample run to check shape and thus no. of dims -

```
In [103]: data = np.random.rand(4,5)

In [104]: data[:,0].shape    # Originally
Out[104]: (4,)

In [105]: data[:,0,None].shape
Out[105]: (4, 1)

In [106]: data[:,0].reshape(-1,1).shape
Out[106]: (4, 1)
```

Putting those side by side for before and after of using the proposed approach -

```
data            :  (4,5)
data[:,0]       :    (4)
```

The shapes aren't aligned for the automatic broadcasting to happen.

Let's extend -

```
data            :  (4,5)
data[:,0,None]  :  (4,1)
```

The shapes are aligned now for broadcasted subtractions to happen and thus we would have each column being subtracted by the first column. The [`docs on broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) should have a lot more info on this.

Comment: Wow, that's arcane! But works.11 minutes to accept though